# Trying to run a query to restrict on date range and time range

Tags: sql, db2

Like the title I am trying to run a query to fetch records within a given time range (6AM - 12PM) and a date range (July 1rst till October 31st)

To give more background:
Transactions are run every day, multiple times a day. The date and time are stored in one column. The processsed at time is stored in the HH:MM:SS format in the table. The records I am interested in from the table is  TRANSACTION_PROCESS_TIME [how many seconds the transaction took], PROCESS_DATE_TIME [Date and Time the transaction occurred].

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_PROCESS_TIME, TIMESTAMP(PROCESS_DATE_TIME)
FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE
WHERE TIMESTAMP(PROCESS_DATE_TIME) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2023-07-01 00:06:00') AND TIMESTAMP('2023-07-01 00:12:00')
ORDER BY PROCESS_DATE_TIME
```

This works if I were to run it for July 1rst like in the example above. It returns all transactions on that day within the 6AM - 12PM window. However, when I change the date range it completely breaks the conditions.

TLDR: trying to run a query to return transactions run from July 1rst to October 31st which were processed in the time range 6AM - 12PM.

Comment: Save the date also, only the time is will be hard in any rdms

Comment: If I understood you correctly you need to break down your filters by truncating the `PROCESS_DATE_TIME` to only have the date then filter Jul 1 - Oct 31 and then add a separate filter using `extract(HOUR from PROCESS_DATE_TIME) >= 6 and extract(HOUR from PROCESS_DATE_TIME) <= 12`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this query should answer it.

```
SELECT
  TRANSACTION_PROCESS_TIME, TIMESTAMP(PROCESS_DATE_TIME)
FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE
WHERE
  TIMESTAMP(PROCESS_DATE_TIME) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2023-07-01 06:00:00')
                                   AND TIMESTAMP('2023-10-31 12:00:00')
  AND TIME(PROCESS_DATE_TIME) BETWEEN TIME '06:00:00' and TIME '12:00:00'
ORDER BY PROCESS_DATE_TIME
```